# Read iframe content after submit a form in the iframe

Tags: image, events, iframe, bind, synchronization

i'm trying to upload a file trough iframe.

i create the iframe in this way:

```
    <iframe frameBorder="0" height="50px" width="100%" id="iframe-upload"/>
```

after this i append the iframe to the DOM:

```
$('#iframe-upload').contents().find('body').append('<form method="post" action="admin/images/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-upload-image"><input name="data[image]" type="file" id="image-upload" /><input type="button" id="btn"></form>').appendTo("#formupload");
```

to submit i act like this:

```
$("#iframe-upload").contents().find('#btn').bind('click', function(){
    $("#iframe-upload").contents().find('#form-upload-image').submit()

})
```

now, i cannot figure out WHEN i have to call:

```
console.log($("#iframe-upload").contents());
```

to get the content.

The problem is sync between my contents() request and iframe refresh, actually jquery goes first, and AFTER the iframe refreshes. In this way i cannot reach the real response.

p.s.
i've tried live(), on(), change() con the frame content, but all these events fires up only one time ( when i select the file before submitting the form ) and so are useless

thank you in advice

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to grab the contents from the iframe before submitting the form. To achieve this, you can bind a function to the form's onSubmit event.

```
$('#form-upload-image').bind('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log($("#iframe-upload").contents());

    this.submit();
});
```

or possibly

```
$('#form-upload-image').submit( function () {
    console.log($("#iframe-upload").contents());
});
```

This is just off the top of my head.

Comment: i have to grab the content AFTER the iframe reloads no BEFORE :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents after the iframe is loaded.

```
$('#iframe').load(function () {
    $(this).contents();
});
```